problem with docker-compose for wordpress
I recently update my docker to the latest version (version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b), and I keep having issues with the my dockerized wordpress.
When I run my docker-compose, some CSS related to header and footer are not loading despite they are in my files.
I tried to replace MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD with PMA_PASSWORD and add PMA_USER. I even tried to add a volumes: - db_data:/var/lib/mysql to phpmyadmin, however it didn't work as well.
docker-compose.yml code:
version: '3.9'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php8.2
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
      PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 256M
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.39
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db_data:



Which is it? Are you having trouble loading CSS or establishing a database connection? Narrow your question down to one problem at a time please.
